# Service Workers cache doesn’t update

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I’m trying to cache static assets in service worker. But when I edit some static files and close the tab and open it again I don’t see any changes.

My cache doesn’t update. If I clear the site data in chrome web tools and reopen tab I see new changes.

Please, see my code below.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('static')
      .then(function(cache) {
        cache.addAll([
            '/index.html',
            '/src/js/app.js',
            '/src/css/app.css'
        ]);
     })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   event.respondWith(
     caches.match(event.request)
   );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **cache versioning**.

```
var STATIC_CACHE_VERSION = '1';
```

The function below will flush the cache every time you change `STATIC_CACHE_VERSION` variable.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function(keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
          if (key !== 'static-' + STATIC_CACHE_VERSION) {
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome try to press `Ctrl + Shift + I`, click on Application, then on Service Workers. In this tab you are able to unregister whatever worker you would like.

Comment: Other option is pressing ```Ctrl + Shift + R``` to reload the tab without cache